# Show that if the eigenvalues of a real matrix are not real, then the matrix cannot be symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

[Question for the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IusKS.png)

I have not been able to make any progress in this problem and would appreciate any help if possible.  I have been able to prove that eigenvalues of a symmetric matrix are real.

Comment: Then you’re done (by logic). (You just said) If the matrix is symmetric then it’s eigenvalues are real. Let’s suppose your matrix is symmetric. Then it’s eigenvalues are real. Contradiction!

Comment: Yeah logically I can deduce it, but i think I have to find a way to show that the above holds.

Comment: Proof by contraposition is totally fine, mathematically @UMass1234

Comment: Do you know how to form the contrapositive of "If A then B"?  What is the contrapositive of "If A is a symmetric matrix, the eigenvalues of A are all real"?

Comment: Proof by any means is fine. So, in particular, @AhmedS.Attaalla's suggestion is perfectly good.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $Av = \lambda v$ with $\lambda $ complex and $A$ real.

Then $x^* Ax = x^* (\lambda x) = \lambda \|x\|^2$
and $(A x)^* x = x^* A^T x= \overline{\lambda} \|x\|^2$.

Hence $x^* (A -A^T) x = (\lambda - \overline{\lambda}) \|x\|^2 \neq 0$.
In particular, we must have $A \ne A^T$.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I understood the idea of using contrapositive but, I was assuming my professor was looking for something shown more directly.  Thank you again.